# Jest- testing variables inside component methods

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs, tdd, enzyme

Let's say I have a class component that has something like this:

```
export class Math extends React.Component {
    ...
    someComponentMethod = numb => {
        const sample = numb * 10 
        ...
        const result = numb -5
        return result
    }
```

Is it possible to make test assertions on `sample` variable in Jest?

Comment: I don't believe it's technically possible. What's your motivation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not possible to write assertions for the private internals of functions.

I've personally found this barrier to encourage better tests to be written. By testing only the public API for correctness, you have the ability to refactor internals without having to update any tests. The existing tests continue to enforce that internal changes work correctly.

Writing tests against internal behavior easily increases the maintenance effort of the code being tested. Since the tests become more tightly coupled to the source code, they'll need more attention when making changes. This can also degrade the reliability of the tests, since more changes to the tests increases the likelihood of bugs manifesting in the tests themselves.

If you find yourself wanting to test some internal behavior, it might be a good time to extract some functionality. In your example, the `sample` value calculation could be extracted into a pure function of its own:

```
export class Math extends React.Component {
    ...

    computeSampleValue(input) {
        return input * 10
    }

    someComponentMethod = numb => {
        const sample = this.computeSampleValue(numb)
        ...
        const result = numb -5
        return result
    }
}
```

You can now assert that whatever logic is being used to calculate the `sample` value works as expected for various inputs. This extraction of logic often makes `someComponentMethod` more readable as well.

If you absolutely need to test some other internal behavior and are aware of the increased code debt, you can have your method perform side effects and write assertions for those. For example, instead of defining `sample` as a function-scope variable, create a `this.sample` property on the component instance and update that. In a test you then call the target method, and afterwards assert that `componentInstance.sample` was changed as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
What I've ended up doing was creating a component state. The only purpose is just to check the internal variable by `setState` and from there I have access to it via jest

Comment: That works, just be aware that using `setState` will cause the component to rerender. If your `render()` method doesn't use the property, then those rerenders are wasted computations. If the property is only used for testing, consider using a normal class property (`this.sample = ...`) instead of state.

Answer (score -3):

I've managed to test a certain variable value inside a function the following way:

sum1.js

```
function sum() {
    result = 1 + 2;
 };

module.exports = sum;
```

sum1.test.js

```
const sum = require('./sum1');

sum();

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(result).toBe(3);
});
```

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: `result` would not be defined when you run this test